# SKMaps Error When upload play store

Tags: android, skmaps, android-security

Sorry but I have a problem when upload my app android to play store. The app use skobbler maps. And I use the version of skmaps that is in the example project (3.0.0) and I get

Vulnerability

Libpng library
The vulnerabilities were fixed in libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher. You can find more information about how resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article.

Whats I can do ??

Answer (score 1):

Please see the skobbler forums where this issue has been documented since June: http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7631-Android-Google-Play-Developer-libpng-warning